# Freeform Pro // Summary Page

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

i am working on a multipage form with FFPro.
It has 4 pages where the user needs to enter data.
At the end ( page 5 ) i would like to offer a summary page, where all data that was entered is shown as a summary.
Here i do not want to show input fields, just the entered value.
I just cant find a way to get the data-value of the field.

Is there no way to access live-data in form-fields?

Thanks 4 any help!

Patrick

Comment: In documentation there i found a solution for this, but i would not have looked up at the multipage section... Anyhow, whoever is interested:

{freeform:mp_data:first_name} will just output the entered data for a field (short-)named "first_name" given by the user.

Comment: Please move your fix into an answer below.